# Safely passing a password (a stack trace issue)

Tags: php

I noticed my dev server's php_errors.log file had reappeared after my previous bug-fixing spree, but this time I noticed something rather disturbing...

> [06-Jan-2016 01:29:29 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory in /home/niet/public_html/classes/DB.class.php:14
>   Stack trace:
>   #0 /home/niet/public_html/classes/DB.class.php(14): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=loca...', 'niet', '**MY ACTUAL PASSWORD!**', Array)
>   #1 /home/niet/public_html/classes/DB.class.php(47): DB::connect()
>   #2 ...

Needless to say, this is an issue. So basically, my question is very simple:

**How can I pass a string to a function, without it showing up in the stack trace if something goes wrong?**

In an attempt to be clever, I tried this:

```
new PDO(
    "mysql:host=localhost.....",
    "niet",
    new class { public function __toString() { return "correct horse battery staple"; }}
);
```

While it successfully connected to the database, a thrown exception (eg. wrong password) still shows the string value, not the anonymous class. A similar issue occurs if I use a "normal" class to try and "hide" the variable from the trace.

Comment: +1 for xkcd ref. Why is it an issue though with the password in the stack trace? Surely whoever has access to the server logs also have access to the config file(s)?

Comment: Perhaps you could use try and catch.. http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php and in production always disable error_reporting..

Comment: @JimL While that's true, I don't like the idea of information that potentially needs to be kept secure ending up dropped in places they're not supposed to be. For example, it was my DB password here, but what if it were a user's account password that wound up in the trace? Or their personal information?

Comment: Surely you don't store users passwords in a database ?

Comment: Simple answer - you can't pass a string to a function so that it doesn't show in stack trace - although you can configure PDO a bit. You can also come up with different disaster scenarios that you can't protect against, which are potentially ruining the fabric of time-space. As you are definitely aware so far, what you can do is use the best known practices available to minimize the security issues - for example, I would use SSL along with MySQL password (not HTTP SSL but PHP > MySQL SSL)

Comment: @adeneo Of course not, only their hashes, but if the error happened in the login or password change areas, that could result in the plaintext password being in the trace.

Comment: Part of security is controlling and auditing access to log files, I don't think there's a way you can 100% guarantee no sensitive data will ever appear in the logs, but there are steps you can take to mitigate it.

Comment: @nickb Yeah... That sounds right actually. And JimL's initial comment too... I guess I just saw my password in there and panicked a bit XD I have gone and ensured that nobody can access the error log (for good measure, I've added a .htaccess rule to deny access to any .log file, as there are a few around for various checks) and I should be all set now. Thanks all.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol also note that the directory structure of frameworks like Symfony place these files outside of the public directory. Might be worth considering (moving the files). Feels a bit better knowing that they shouldn't be possible to reach for outside users

Comment: In deployment (next month) I'll consider moving the processing files (classes, modules etc.) out of the `public_html` folder, leaving only the `index.php` entrypoint - this would be a simple case of changing the `chdir` at the start of my script and everything would just go together like a dream (aren't I clever sometimes?)

Answer (score 0):

In a productive environment, you should disable any error messages. Set `display_errors = off` in your PHP.ini file to not reveal any details about your server.

Also, you can set `$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT)` to silence PDO. You can check the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php) for more error codes.

// Edit: Errors can still be logged in silent mode:

```
$pdo = new PDO($server, $user, $password);

// Let us assume that 'foo' column does not exist
$query  = 'SELECT foo FROM bar';
$result = $pdo->query($query);

// Log error message
if ($pdo->errorInfo()) {
  print_r($pdo -> errorInfo());
}
```

Comment: Error messages are caught and handled by a global exception handler, but my concern here is with the internal logs generated by PHP's error logging. Also, silent errors are the worst idea ever :p

Comment: Actually, ``ERRMODE_SILENT`` is the default value. You can still log errors in silent mode. I updated my answer accordingly. Also, in productive environments, you most likely never want to expose error messages.

Comment: I think a global exception catcher is still the better option here - if I really need to do something specific to database errors: `if( $globalerror instanceof PDOException)` :3

Answer (score 0):

You could set your own exception handler and just print the exception message instead of the stack trace, e.g.

```
function exception_handler($e) {
    echo "<b>Exception in file: </b>" . $e->getFile() . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Exception on line: </b>" . $e->getLine() . "<br>";
    echo "<b>Exception message: </b>" . $e->getMessage();
}

set_exception_handler('exception_handler');
```

So you would still end up with a useful error message, but not containing any sensitive data:

> **Exception in file:** C:\xampp\htdocs\path\file.php
>   **Exception on line:** 220
>   **Exception message:** SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using >password: YES)

Comment: Well sure, I can do that, and in fact I do already have a global exception handler. But without the trace, how can I hope to find the cause of an error? ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol You can print the file and the line of the [exception](http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php) so you would exactly know from where it comes from. But you just don't output the trace.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol updated the answer with an exception handler so you know exactly where the error is.

Comment: Again though... more often than not the error is caused by the arguments passed somewhere in the trace not being what was expected.